# Python-based script to delete lines from file, that presented in another file

Tags: python, loops

I have a file `all_projects.txt`, that contains:

```
java/my_project_wwe
java/my_project_wwf
java/my_project_wcw
net/my_project_aew
net/my_project_impact
net/my_project_njpw
```

I have another file `project_to_delete.txt`, that contains:

```
java/my_project_wcw
net/my_project_njpw
```

In a result, I want to receive:

```
java/my_project_wwe
java/my_project_wwf
net/my_project_aew
net/my_project_impact
```

It is working perfect via bash:
`grep -v -x -f project_to_delete.txt all_projects.txt` 
But i want to do it via python.
Of course we can do, something like, module `os.system` or `subprocess`, but it is not, that I am looking.
I tried to do this:

```
with open('all_projects.txt','r') as read1:
  f1 = read1.readlines()

with open('project_to_delete.txt', 'r') as read2:
  f2 = read2.readlines()

with open('result.txt', 'w+') as write1:
  for line in f1:
    if line in f2:
      write1.write(line + '\n')
```

But in `result.txt`, I have:

```
java/my_project_wcw

net/my_project_njpw
```

Where I have an error ? 
Thanks for You attention, and thanks for Your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your if condition is not correct. You are finding lines which are same in both f1 and f2. Your if condition should be **if line not in f2**

```py
with open('result.txt', 'w+') as write1:
    for line in f1:
        if line not in f2:  #Nottice the not here
            write1.write(line + '\n')
```

Answer (score 1):

@Saad_Khan's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67365482/982257) is correct, but I just wanted to raise a point about your question that I try to emphasize whenever I read questions like this, which is a point about data abstraction.

The way you wrote your question is about "deleting lines in a file" that are the same as "lines in another file".  But does your question really depend so much on *files*?  In this case maybe a little bit, since you mentioned doing the same with `grep`, and where command-line utilities like `grep` tend to be file/stream-oriented.

But in programming languages like Python you might try to think less about "files" and more about the data structures serialized in those files.  In this case just lists of strings.

So your question becomes, how do take the difference of two lists of strings?  Because the way you originally wrote the question you are just reading the full contents of the files into lists using `readlines()` anyways (the question might be a little different if you are iterating over large files, but not by much).

So how do you take the difference between two lists?

One easy way is to use [`set.difference`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#frozenset.difference):

```py
>>> list_a = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
>>> list_b = [3, 5, 6]
>>> set_c = set(list_a).difference(list_b)
>>> set_c
set([1, 2, 4])
```

Since `set` is not guaranteed to be ordered, if you want the output to be predictable you can sort the output:

```py
>>> list_c = sorted(set_c)
```

However, a more common pattern is more like @Saad_Khan's answer, which *preserves* the original order of list `a`; you can do this with a list comprehension like:

```py
>>> list_c = [s for s in list_a if s not in list_b]
```

However, this can be a little slow since if `list_b` is large it has to perform string comparisons over up to every element of `list_b` (in the worst case) per loop.  So a more common pattern is to make a `list_b` into a `set`:

```py
>>> set_b = set(list_b)
>>> list_c = [s for s in list_a if s not in set_b]
```

The advantage to this is that every `if s not in set_b` has O(1) behavior, whereas `if s not in list_b` has O(n) behavior on the size of `list_b`.

Now that you have these more general techniques in your toolbelt, worrying about what to do with the results is a completely separate and independent problem from reading/writing files.

Given `list_c` you are now free to write this to a third file in any way.  Or if you want to write a command-line utility like `grep` sometimes it's useful to just call `print()` and allow the user to use shell redirection if they want to output the results to a file:

```py
>>> print('\n'.join(list_c))
```